# Google Analyitcs with gms version 11.4.0 or higher is not working with instant apps when run on Nought Devices

Tags: google-analytics, google-play-services, android-instant-apps

We want to transfer data from instant app to installed app using **Cookie API**. Cookie API needs to have a *play services version 11.4.0 or more*. It works on lollipop, marshmallow and Oreo devices but crashes on Nought devices only showing following exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.app.job.IJobScheduler.cancel(int)' on a null object reference.
```

It crashes when we use `GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getContext())` to get the Google Analytics Instance. But it works on all platforms except Nought.

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: Like Kyle mentioned, double check the Google Play services for Instant Apps on your device and make sure it is up-to-date, currently >= 2.2. Also, make sure your Android Studio is up-to-date too, older versions can force an older version of Google Play services for IA onto your device before building the IA. If none of this work, then file a bug using Pragati's link.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the same as [this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/EAF4KZsB7I0).

If that's the case, then this should fix it.

> This is normally fixed in Google Play services for Instant Apps version 2.3. However, when you provision your device with Android Studio, you no longer receive OTA updates. You can check that from the version number (Android Studio provisioned version contains "sdk").
>
> Try uninstalling Google Play services for Instant Apps. Then turn off Instant Apps and turn it on again. It should restore the final version (2.6-release), which contains the fix.

Deploying from the IDE will overwrite it still though.

So once it's updated, you can also remove the forced provision from the Edit Configuration dialog.

This was my issue with Firebase Analytics and I got the same error. So try that out and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Updating Google play services for instant apps works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there any way to show a dialog when play services for A.I.A are not updated?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. The only reason you're seeing play services out of date is because when you deploy the instant app from your computer, it overwrites the Play Services on the device. Our Vimeo instant app had crash reporting in production and I've never seen the crash happen in the wild. It's just a development crash. That being said, I believe you technically can get access to the version of play services.